# Qt/C++ Write/Read Key-Value Pair File

Tags: c++, qt, file-io

I have a Qt/C++ widget based application for the Mac. I have a series of checkboxes, radio buttons, and text fields for storing settings. I want to save them to a key value pair file when I click an Update button, and then when the application loads, read this file to set those widgets back to the proper states.

Is there an example for how this is done somewhere?

Comment: You could looke at [the detailed description of the QFile class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#details) which has a lot of examples on opening, writing to and reading from files.

Comment: Hmmm... it appears I may need to use [QSettings API](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) as the best choice.

Comment: For settings this may be the better option. But keep in mind how they are stored (user-account based, system wide etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I used on a Mac. However, if you modify the `setPath()` of your `settings` object, you can make it work on other platforms via [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#QSettings).

In `mainwindow.h`, I had to add these entries:

```
void readSettings();
void writeSettings();
```

under Private Slots.

Then, in `mainwindow.cpp`, I added these example functions:

```
void MainWindow::readSettings()
{
    QSettings settings;
    settings.setPath(settings.IniFormat,settings.SystemScope,"/etc/xdg");
    settings.beginGroup("General");
    ui->checkBox1->setChecked(settings.value("checkBox1",false).toBool());
    settings.endGroup();
}

void MainWindow::writeSettings()
{
    QSettings settings;
    settings.setPath(settings.IniFormat,settings.SystemScope,"/etc/xdg");
    settings.beginGroup("General");
    settings.setValue("checkBox1",ui->checkBox1->isChecked());
    settings.endGroup();
}
```

You should read about "scope" and `setPath()` on the [QSettings page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#QSettings) for more information.

Then, in `MainWindow::MainWindow()` function, I had it like so:

```
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("Example Company");
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain("example.com");
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("Example Product");

ui->setupUi(this);
this->readSettings();
```

Note that you can only `readSettings()` after you have set the `ui` variable. And by using the `QCoreApplication` class like I did, I don't have to keep redeclaring what settings I'm using all the time.

Then, I took the `MainWindow` and added a `checkBox1` and an `updateButton` on it, and set the updateButton `clicked()` slot code to this:

```
this->writeSettings();
```

Now when the window loads, after the UI is drawn, it reads the settings to set the checkbox value to whatever you set when you clicked the update button.

Comment: In your `readSettings()` I would do a `settings.contains(...)` first to see if the value is set or use the `defaultValue` parameter of the `settings.value()` function. Otherwise you don't know what is put in your widgets in case the settings value is missing for some reason.

Comment: @Bowdzone I'll update that in a few hours (heading to bed). However, I ran into another odd situation. The docs say system scope on Mac is stored in directory "/etc/xdg", but I cannot find this directory on my Mac. I'm thinking the docs must not explain what happens on Yosemite (OSX 10.10). Do you know where the system scope settings are now stored?

Comment: I never had a Mac in my life and I know nothing about it sorry.

Comment: I've now implemented the `defaultValue` part of the `value()` class method.

Comment: I've also put out a [query](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31994646/105539) on the /etc/xdg concern.