# Where does Qt/C++ Store System Scope QSettings on Mac OSX 10?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qsettings

According to Qt's docs for the latest Qt version, looking at [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#QSettings), they say that system scope of settings on a Mac are stored in a directory /etc/xdg. Unfortunately, I'm not finding this to be the case on Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite. Where do they store these settings? I mean, I've gotten QSettings to work [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31972646/105539), but no /etc/xdg folder is to be found even when I do `sudo su` and assume root on my Mac in order to access that folder.

Answer (score 4):

On a MacOS, `$HOME/Library/Preferences/` should be the location for user settings, while `/Library/Preferences/` is the path for default settings (and a user can't write on it).

If on newer version of MacOS Qt uses the Unix' paths, then you should look at `/etc/xdg/` or `$HOME/.config/`

In all the four cases, those directory contains a single `.rc` file and (optionally) a subir named as the software which contains all other config files.

Comment: In my case, `/etc/xdg` doesn't exist on my Mac Air with Yosemite. I even did `sudo su` in a Terminal prompt to become root and checked. I do see a `/Library/Preferences` and a `$HOME/Library/Preferences`, however. Even though I'm doing system scope, it seems to be creating a file under `$HOME/Library/Preferences` even though I specified `/etc/xdg` with the `QSettings::setPath()` statement. I am concerned because I need system scope here, not user scope.

Comment: So, you can't install files in `/etc/xdg`, because it's not a settings path; you can put config files in `/Library/Preferences` when you install the app (and a normal user won't modify it) and keep a user version in `$HOME/Library/Preferences`; if you want to change this behaviour, you must instruct Qt to use another path (but I don't know if you can do it and how)